# Sort the rows and group it with same sorted order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, sql-order-by

First I want to sort by date column asc. And then group by name column .
For example,

```
Name     date(mmddyyyy)
 A.      03/10/2020
 B.      03/09/2020
 C.      03/13/2020
 B.      03/11/2020
 A.      03/12/2020
 C.      03/12/2020
```

Required output,

```
Name     Date
 B.      03/09/2020
 B.      03/11/2020
 A.      03/10/2020
 A.      03/12/2020
 C.      03/12/2020
 C.      03/13/2020
```

I want to SQL query to achieve this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
order by
    min(date) over(partition by name),
    date
```

If there is a possibility of tied groups, then you can add the `name` as second sort criteria to avoid mixing the groups:

```
order by
    min(date) over(partition by name),
    name,
    date
```